# Smoothing Edgeflow

Tags: edges

Im looking for a tool to smooth an edgeflow automaticaly. When you got a lot of polys it becomes a massive amount of work to smooth edges manually.

Here is an image of what I want to smooth. 
[image]

And here another one zoomed in for a detail
[image]

So there are little bumps here and there in the edgeflow and I ask myself if Blender got a tool to smooth it automatically

Thanks for any sugestions and 
Best regards

Comment: W > Smooth doesn't help?

Comment: nono, there are already too many vertecies. After subdivide-smoothing it the little bumps stay

Comment: I'm not talking about subdivide+smooth but simple Smooth. Also, you could delete some vertices if you have too many, for example with the Select > Checker Deselect

Comment: Why not to use curves? Try to apply some decimate modifier, and convert to curves to eventually find that life if actually not so hard. ;-)

Comment: Oh I missunderstoon =0 
W - Smooth really was the tool that I was looking for =) Thank you!!

(The checker deselect is a great idea  as well, but in this case I really wanted to keep the polys as they are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you could simplify your mesh with the *Checker Deselect* (play with the parameters on the bottom of the *Tools* panel) and *Dissolve Vertices*. Then you could <kbd>W</kbd> > *Smooth* and again play with the parameters.

[image]

Comment: Thats it! I have done it like this and my edges are smooth like butter. Thank you so much!